# Entity Framework Core - Union - how to merge two entities

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, linq-to-entities

Trying to fetch an http result from two different entities:

```
[HttpGet("{id}")]
public async Task<ActionResult<CourseDto>> Getcourse(string id)
{
    var course = _context1.Courses.Where(c => c.Id == id);

    string userId = course.Select(c => c.TeacherId).ToString();

    var teacher = _context2.Users
        .Where(u => u.Id == userId)
        .Select(u => new {TeacherId = u.Id, TeacherName = u.userName});

    var union = 
        course.Select(c => new {
                        Id = c.Id,
                        Title = c.Title,
                        CourseImages = c.CourseImages.ToList().Select(x => new {x.File}),
        }).FirstOrDefault()
        .Union<CourseDto>(teacher.Select(u => new {
                TeacherId = u.TeacherId,
                TeacherName = u.TeacherName
            })).FirstOrDefault();

    return Ok(union);                
}

public class CourseDto
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string TeacherId { get; set; }
    public string TeacherName { get; set; }
    public ICollection<CourseImagesDto> CourseImages { get; set; }
}
```

I got error pointing to course in the union variable saying:

> <anonymous type: string Id, string Title, IEnumerable << anonymous
> type: string File >> CourseImages> 'does not contain a definition for'
> Union 'and the best extension method overload' Enumerable.Union
>  (IEnumerable , IEnumerable )
> 'requires a receiver of type' IEnumerable

Even I remove the `CourseImages` collection from the `Course` type, and even I've tried to replace `Union` by `Concat`, I keep seeing the same error, so what am I doing wrong here ?

Comment: FirstOrDefault is not an Enumerable, so it does support Union, you want to use Take(1).

Comment: @MarcG Take(1) doesn't work, same error keeps showing.

Answer (score 1):

A quick fix to your code would look something like this

```cs
var selectedCourse = course.FirstOrDefault();
var selectedTeacher = teacher.FirstOrDefault();

var union = new List<object>() {
    new {
        Id = selectedCourse.Id,
        Title = selectedCourse.Title,
        CourseImages = selectedCourse.CourseImages.ToList().Select(x => new { x.File }),
    },
    new {
        TeacherId = selectedTeacher.TeacherId,
        TeacherName = selectedTeacher.TeacherName
    }
};
```

There are several things you need to fix and improve:

```cs
// The Where extension method is returning an IEnumerable of course and NOT a single course object
var course = _context1.Courses.Where(c => c.Id == id);

// What you want is 
var course = _context1.Courses.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Id == id);

// You're doing a ToString() on an object instead of on the TeacherId
string userId = course.Select(c => c.TeacherId).ToString();

// What you want is
var course = _context1.Courses.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Id == id);
string userId = course.TeacherId.ToString()
```

If you need a single object with the properties of both Course and Teacher, you can create an anonymous object

```
var union = new {
    Id = selectedCourse.Id,
    Title = selectedCourse.Title,
    CourseImages = selectedCourse.CourseImages.ToList().Select(x => new { x.File }),
    TeacherId = selectedTeacher.TeacherId,
    TeacherName = selectedTeacher.TeacherName
};
```

Comment: You pointed me to the right direction, your code provides a list of two objects, while a union has to be done to merge two entities. In other hand I'd ask if is there a way to keep the method asynchronous.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want a single object with the fields of both course and teacher, right?

Comment: Sorry for the delay to answer, yes, that's right, only one object with fields coming from two different entities.

Comment: I updated my answer, check if it's what you're looking for

Comment: This is not involving EF Union as asked in the question, but this is a good workaround.